# How can I select a vertex/edge/face created by modifer, without applying modifier

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

After using a modifier, how can I select a vertex/edge/face created by modifier, without applying the modifier?

Comment: Why not using multires modifier instead?

Comment: For *some* modifiers will work turning on `Display modifier in Edit mode` and `Adjust edit cage` buttons in modifiers properties (like Array, Solidify, Mirror)

Comment: Nope, that's not possible - There is no 'Edit Mesh Modifier' like in Max at the moment to edit the geometry afterwards. The only solid option you have is adding a lattice to deform your geometry.